# About uninstallation of Ubuntu to allow dual-boot

Tags: 11.10, installation, windows

I had windows XP and windows 7 previously. I wanted to keep windows XP and replace windows 7 by Ubuntu in a specific drive of hard disk.

During installation of Ubuntu I found option replace windows 7 by Ubuntu and I did it. now I found that windows XP has also gone and Ubuntu is occupying the area of whole hard disk.

Now I want to uninstall or format the hard disk because Ubuntu is new to me and I am not comfortable with Ubuntu only right now. I want to keep both windows XP and Ubuntu. so how can I uninstall Ubuntu or format hard disk??

please help....Is the formatting is possible by inserting windows XP CD?? Or is there any other way so that without uninstalling Ubuntu I can also install windows XP?

Answer (score 0):

All of the Windows XP, Windows 7 and Ubuntu installation procedures allow you to format your hard disk. It's usually easiest to install Windows first, leaving a partition available for Ubuntu, then install Ubuntu making sure to overwrite the boot sector with GRUB (the Grand Unified Boot Loader). This will allow you to 'dual-boot' and use both OSs.